# Jquery UI sortable меняем положение всех элементов

Tags: jquery-ui

Добрый день уважаемые профи. Я не силён в английском, поэтому API по Jquery UI sortable не очень пойму, вернее не найду того, что мне нужно.
Наверняка Вы видели в wordpress есть сортировка категорий благодаря перетаскиванию, вот и я хочу так же сделать.
Проблема в том, что у меня перетаскиваются только соседние элементы.

**Подскажите глупому, как сделать, что бы можно было вытянуть например li из одного ul и поместить в другой ul ?**
Список вложен в список и так далее, т.е. многоуровневый список.

Comment: Странно. Не обязательно знать английский, чтоб посмотреть `source`. Все там видно сразу https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists   Есть один `ul`  с айдишником, есть другой - с другим айдишником, Их объединяет один класс, по которому идет коннект. Или любое другое свойство. За коннект отвечает свойство `connectWith`.

Comment: Спасибо очень помог!